# Read cookie in javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

This is my asp code, can be the same done in Javascript?

```
HttpCookie cookie = this.Request.Cookies["Votes"];
if (cookie != null)
    if (cookie.Values.Get(id.ToString()) == "true")  return true;
return false;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function readTheCookie(the_info)
{
// load the cookie into a variable and unescape it

 var the_cookie = document.cookie;
 var the_cookie = unescape(the_cookie);

// separate the values from the cookie name

 var broken_cookie = the_cookie.split("some parameter"); // parameter depends on how the cookie is stored
 var the_values = broken_cookie["some index"]; // index of the value that you want
}
```

These are all the parts of reading a cookie, you can use this snippet to achieve what you want.

Comment: var the_cookie = unescape(the_cookie) just returns "Votes" without any values.

Comment: while the var the_cookie = document.cookie; returns:
 the_cookie = "Votes=47=true&31=true&48=true"

Comment: ans where do you use the_info parameter?

Comment: the_info is just a dummy parameter that i gave .. not to bother about it :) ; unescape(the_cookie) is mentioned because generally we escape the cookie while storing, may not be applicable all the time.. ; Its good that your cookie is getting values .. now split the cookie first with "&" parameter and the resulting strings with "=" as parameter in split function and do the rest .. :)

Comment: is it possible to load only the "Votes" cookie? Because if i have more cookies on page, the_cookie = document.cookie; will return all of them concatenated in one string.

Comment: try the_cookie = document.cookie["Votes"]; let me know .. :)

Comment: the_cookie = document.cookie; the_cookie["Votes"] .. I think this should work other wise we have to split and get the values ..

Comment: sorry dani .. i am also a beginner software developer .. I shared to the extent that I know .. I will message you once I learn more about cookies .. good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

document.cookie gives you access to the cookies in JavaScript.  You will need to do some parsing to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

using this code

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
            var exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }


function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

function GetSetCookie() {
            var version = getCookie("version");
            if (version != null && version != "") {
                if (version == 'full') {
                    version = 'text';
                }
                else {
                    version = 'full';
                }
            }
            else {
                version = 'full';
            }
            setCookie("version", version, 365);
            window.top.location.reload();
        }
```

Comment: Did you copy this from http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp ?

If so, you should disclose it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this code in [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)  which works for me

```
  function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
        user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
        if (user != "" && user != null) {
            setCookie("username", user, 365);
        }
    }
}
```