# Accessing cookies in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read cookie in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454619/read-cookie-in-javascript)

I have written the following function.  I need to access cookies using the format `$COOKIE['cookieName']`.

```
var $COOKIE = (function(){
    if(!document.cookie)
        return {};
    else{
        var c = document.cookie.split(';');
        var len = c.length;

        var ret = {};
        var temp ;

        for( var i = 0 ; i < len ; ++i )
        {
            temp = c[i].split('=');

            ret[temp[0]] = temp[1];
        }

        return ret;
    }
})();
```

I have set two cookies a1= 2 , a2 = 9.  `$COOKIE['a1']` gives me 2, but `$COOKIE['a2']` is undefined.

Why is it happening?  What is the problem in my logic/code?

Comment: @Rocket -- it was a bad java / javascript joke

Comment: Probably a [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454619/read-cookie-in-javascript)

Comment: Beware that you'll need to call this function every time `document.cookie` changes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Problem is that you're splitting by ";" but the values in a cookie are separated by "; " (semicolon + whitespace). Thus your second value would be `" a2": 9`

To fix it, simply add a whitespace to the delimiter or use this snippet for a more data-centric approach ;)

```
var $COOKIE = (document.cookie || '').split(/;\s*/).reduce(function(re, c) {
  var tmp = c.match(/([^=]+)=(.*)/);
  if (tmp) re[tmp[1]] = unescape(tmp[2]);
  return re;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i += 1) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x === c_name) {
            return (unescape(y));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP is specifically asking about how to create a map of all the cookies so it can be accessed with bracket notation. This is a fine workaround, but not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

you have

```
 var len = a.length;
```

it should be

```
var len = c.length;
```

if you want to cycle through the array of cookies. (Note the 'C' instead of 'A'). That's why you get the first one only, because it cycles only once. Not the real length of the array